# How to paginate in Grails?

Tags: java, grails, pagination, grails-orm

I am new to grails and I'm trying to achieve pagination in my application.
I have followed the example in the documentation but nothing seems to happen, It cannot render the page navigation buttons. Here's the example code:

```
def transaction = DataEntry.findAll() as List
    render(model: [transactions: transaction, total: transaction.count ], view: "/Transactions/verify")
```

then in my view I have put this:

```
<g:each var="transaction" in="${transactions}">
    <h1>${transaction.sendersName}</h1>
</g:each>

<g:paginate next="Forward"
            prev="Back"
            maxsteps="1" 
            controller="approvedTransaction"
            action="index" 
            total="${total}" />
```

any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried passing the `params` also as an input to the `paginate` tag? Like params="${params}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this example

**domain class:**

```
class DataEntry{
    String sendersName
}
```

**controller:**

```
class TransactionsController {
    def list() {
        [data: DataEntry.list(params), dataEntryCount: DataEntry.count()]
    }
}
```

**Paginate code:**

```
<g:paginate controller="transactions" action="list" total="${dataEntryCount}" />
```

**OR**

```
<g:paginate next="Forward" prev="Back"
            maxsteps="0" controller="transactions"
            action="list" total="${dataEntryCount}" />
```

Please refer [documentation](http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Tags/paginate.html) for more details